# Cant load pods that are made with swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to import Bond and import ConvenienceKit. I have included in my podfile

```
pod 'Bond', '~> 3.7'
pod 'ConvenienceKit'
use_frameworks!
end
```

It is properly installed and open the file as workspace. However I cannot import it. If I see the my file's framework I see that pod_appname.framework is red.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Xcode doesn't provide AutoComplete functionality for "import" statement in swift.

So, you just need to make sure that you are importing the file with its specified name in framework.

Do the following things and you can import any swift file from "Pods"

> 1) Clean your project
>
> 2) Make sure that all your "Pods" > "Build Settings" > "Build Active
>   Architecture Only" is set to "NO".
>
> 3) Don't run, just build your project.
>
> 4) Now, import any file from "Pods" to any swift file
>
> `E.g.: import Bond`
>
> 5) Again, build project and it will work as expected. Finally, you can
>   access it properties
>
> 6) Similarly, you can import different files
>
> ```
> import Bond+UIImageView
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK There is no Bond.framework in my project I have just installed it in my pods.

Comment: @Satsuki Fine, I have just taken an example

Answer (score 0):

You need to have bridging header to import pod frameworks when using Swfit.

The easiest way is to add a new dummy objective c file to the project. To do that, go to Xcode menu file >new >file. Under "iOS", choose "Source">"Cocoa Touch Class", and go to next. Make Sure to choose language "Objective C". Then it will ask you whether you want to add bridging header at that point. Choose to add it.

You can now delete the dummy objective C files. Inside bridging header file, import your pod frame work `#import "someframework.h"`. Then you can use the frame works inside your `Swift` files.

**Add Header Manually**

Go to Xcode Menu, file > new > file, Under `iOS`, choose Source > Header file. Name your file something like `YourAppName-Bridging-Header` (just to be noticeable in future). Make sure to choose target to your app. Then create it.

You can delete all lines of code inside the header file. And then import as `#import "someframework.h"`.

Then go to your Project, choose your target, then choose Build Settings. In the search field search "objective-c bridging header", and type in your header file name like `YourAppName-Bridging-Header.h`

Comment: It doesn't tell me to add bridging header

Comment: @AlbertMon Bridging is required, if and only if you are using any "Objective-C" framework or file.

Comment: Ok I want to make sure that this project was made in Obj-C so it has an obj-c app delagate. Can this be done?

Comment: @Satsuki the framework are purely written in swift, so you don't need to make bridging header

Comment: @Satsuki try mine, I am using that only!

Comment: @Satsuki oops, sorry about that, didn't know they are in swift.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Thanks for the info! :)

Answer (score 0):

`use_frameworks!` should be at the top, like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'ParseRealmSync' do
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'Parse'
end
```